# Travar Media Screen CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout-responsivo

Boa tarde, gostaria de saber alguma forma de bloquear o usuário de ajustar a resolução na  versão mobile do site(deslizando dois dedos). 
Como neste exemplo: http://gruponzn.com/ (com o navegador do celular você não consegue ficar mechendo no tamanho da resolução.

Este é o site que eu queria "travar" em uma resolução. já tentei com max-width e min-width.
http://novo.cursoasb.com.br/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza-se as ***META TAGs*** do **html**.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

A propriedade initial-scale controla o nível de amplificação quando a página é carregada pela primeira vez. As propriedades maximum-scale, minimum-scale, e user-scalable controlam a permissão para o usuário efetuar aumento ou diminuição da página.

### width

Define uma largura para o viewport. Os valores podem ser em PX ou “device-width”, que determina automaticamente um valor igual a largura da tela do dispositivo. Exemplo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px">
```

### height

Define uma altura para o viewport. Os valores podem ser em PX ou “device-height”, que determina automaticamente um valor igual a altura da tela do dispositivo. Exemplo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">
```

### initial-scale

Define a escala inicial do viewport.

### user-scalable

Define a possibilidade de o usuário fazer “zoom” em um determinado lugar da tela. É ativado quando o usuário bate duas vezes com o dedo em um lugar da tela.

**Fonte**: [**Tableless**](http://tableless.com.br/manipulando-metatag-viewport/)

Comment: Resolveu o meu caso, Obrigado @Antony.
Se usar minimum-scale=1 ou maximum-scale=1 oque tem de diferente?

Comment: Estou complementando a resposta dê uma lida nela que explica direitinho.